# Preventing Apple from writting files to USB drives

Tags: windows, updates, automatic-update, software-update

When I stick a USB drve in a Mac they write all these dot files to it. Is there a way to prevent this?

Why does apple do this.

Comment: As for the question without the question mark http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/invisibles.html this just goes over what each .whatever is used for

Comment: @techie007 Oh, there we go. Flagged.